# Angular router navigate away from outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router

My current url is http:localhost:4200/home/(dialog:login)
I want to navigate to http:localhost:4200/reset-password

The dialog in the url is an outlet which is located in a primeng dialog.

I tryed this command: this.router.navigate(['/reset-password',{ outlets: { dialog: null } }]);

The navigation is working but the dialog:login is still in the url and the dialog is also open.

I got it working, but it is a realy ugly solution. I think this must be possible.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { dialog: null } }]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/reset-password']);
      }, 100);
    }, 100);
```

Comment: How about you have the dialog close on the OnDestroy hook of the component (propably HomeComponent) you are leaving?

Comment: @Chund i tryed this, but it is not updating the url

Comment: Sorry I cannot quite follow you. Without changing the url, the component I meant for you to use, would not be destroyed, therefore th dialog would not close.

Comment: the dialog is a saparate component. To close the dialog, i have to change the route. I can't access the dialog from home component.

Comment: So you are triggering the dialog via your route? Never seen that. Would you prepare a playground?

Comment: i created a stackblitz for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqmhnj

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e23sme works for me

Comment: Thank you so much! I was sure that there must be such a simple solution. But I could not find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: Neat. I'll add our findings as an answer later, just in case somebody stumbles over this question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using multiple router-outlets you have to explicitly tell both outlets what to render on navigation. The `[routerLink]` syntax you used is not quite right.

Your additional router was named `dialog` therefore you need to target the default outlet, which is accessed as `primary`, and your `dialog` outlet seperately.

Here is a simple solution using the injectable `Router`:

```
 reset() {
   this.router.navigate([
     { outlets: { primary: ['password-forgot'], dialog: null } },
   ]);
 }
```